# syslog measurement not appearing in influxdb

Tags: python, macos, influxdb, telegraf, chronograf

**TL;DR Not able to see syslog logs in influxdb**

Environment:

```
OS: mac os mojave
telegraf version: 1.8
influxdb version: 1.6.4
```

So I wanted to view logs in `chronograf` and figured out from the set of [input plugins](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.8/plugins/inputs/) offered in telegraf to use the `syslog` plugin.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://dzone.com/articles/get-your-syslog-on), but have added the steps here too for easy read.

I installed rsyslog via `homebrew` as follows:

```
$ brew install rsyslog
```

Added the following in `/usr/local/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$WorkDirectory /tmp/rsyslog # temporary directory for storing data 
$ActionQueueType LinkedList # use asynchronous processing 
$ActionQueueFileName srvrfwd # set file name, also enables disk mode 
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1 # infinite retries on insert failure 
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save in-memory data if rsyslog shuts down 
$ModLoad imudp #loads the udp module 
#listen for messages on udp localhost:514 
$UDPServerAddress localhost 
$UDPServerRun 514 
*.* @@(o)127.0.0.1:6514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

restarted rsyslog:

```
$ sudo brew services restart rsyslog
```

I configured telegraf as follows:

```
# # Accepts syslog messages per RFC5425
 [[inputs.syslog]]
#   ## Specify an ip or hostname with port - eg., tcp://localhost:6514, tcp://10.0.0.1:6514
#   ## Protocol, address and port to host the syslog receiver.
#   ## If no host is specified, then localhost is used.
#   ## If no port is specified, 6514 is used (RFC5425#section-4.1).
 server = "tcp://localhost:6514"
```

and restarted telegraf as follows:

```
$ brew services restart telegraf
```

But my expectation was to see `syslog` measurement inside of `telegraf`database

I wrote the following python script to log to `syslog` hoping that it would appear in the database:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/var/run/syslog')

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

my_logger.debug('this is debug')
my_logger.critical('this is critical')
```

but to no avail.

What could be wrong here? If so is there a log file I could check in?

**EDIT 1:**

So I troubleshooted rsyslog using the `rsyslogd -N1` command and found some issues:

- The configuration file must be in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.
- The configuration file working directory i.e; `/tmp/rsyslog` wasn't found so created one.
- There were some errors in rsyslog.conf file (can be seen in edits of this question)

After doing all the above I restarted rsyslog and also influxdb and telegraf and checked again if there were any errors by running the `rsyslogd -N1` command and the following is the output:

```
rsyslogd: version 8.37.0, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.
```

Still the same issue persists.

**EDIT 2:**
related post: [syslog-plugin-from-remote-server](https://community.influxdata.com/t/syslog-plugin-from-remote-server/6610/11)